# Knockout Clone Whole Item In foreach

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am trying to clone elements when clicking a button. I was trying to use `ko.toJS`. On page load it works fine, but when I want clone the items, it is unable to bind the items (like, value, Text, etc.).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="stockItems-inner" data-bind="foreach: StockItems">
    <div data-bind="if: Type=='Input'">
        <div class="stock_container_input">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div data-bind="if: Type=='Radio'">
        <div class="stock_container_control">
        <div data-bind="foreach: Options">
            <div class="stockLbl">
               <input type="radio" data-bind="text: Text, checked:$parent.Value, attr:{'id':Id, 'name': $parent.Text, 'value': Value}" />
               <label data-bind="attr:{'for':Id}, text: Text"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="addItem">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: CloneItem"><img src="images/add.png" alt="" /></button>
</div>
```

The View Model:

```
ConfigurationStockViewModel =  function() {
var self = this;


this.StockItems = ko.observableArray();


this.ApplyData = function(data){

    self.StockItems(data.Items);

}

this.CloneItem = function(StockItems){
    self.StockItems.push(ko.toJS(StockItems));
};
};
```

When clicking the button, an error is thrown: `Unable to process binding`. I am using JSON data for binding.

Comment: Is Options defined?: <div data-bind="foreach: Options">

Comment: Yes Option is defined in the json. Inside the options only i have defined all the radio button data. It works fine while page load, but when i want to clone the same data, its throwing an error "Unable to process binding "if: function (){return Type=='Input' }"
Message: Type is not defined ".

Comment: Maybe do a jsfiddle and can take a look

Comment: I have edited somthig in HTML Section, Please Have a look here...  http://jsfiddle.net/WebDevBan/pxHPL/4/ . When we click the button we, the above element (input type and radio buttons) are to be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what end result you want without working code, but sounds like you want to clone the last item in array and add to array?

If so, I think you have an error - your add button click binding will never pass anything to the function you defined, since it is outside the foreach.  You need something like this:

```
this.CloneItem = function() {
    var toClone = self.StockItems()[self.StockItems().length - 1]
    self.StockItems.push(toClone);
};
```

Here is a simplified example without radio buttons, etc:

http://jsfiddle.net/5J47L/